# Fact vs Time dimension tables linked by period of time in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query-performance, dimensions, rollup

I am used to work in PowerBI which helps a lot in regards to work with a star model, fact-dimension and performance issues.

However, now I have to "create" a time dimension to calculate some metrics in **MySQL**. For some reasons, we cannot connect a PowerBI into that, so most of the job has to be done manually.

In fact, I do have a time dimension table ([link](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/setting-up-a-time-dimension-table-in-mysql/)) , awesome. I have several other dimensional tables (such as business unit, department, ... ) that are linked to the Fact table using a view . This view has the **Start date** and **End date** of some tasks.

So, I created a relation between timeline and the fact table using a LEFT JOIN matching the date (bigger than start date and smaller than the end date) such as:

```
SELECT `time_dimension`.`year` AS `year`,
`time_dimension`.`month` AS `month`,
`time_dimension`.`day` AS `day`,
`view-entry-team_average`.`Business Unit` AS `Business Unit`,
`view-entry-team_average`.`Department` AS `department`,
`view-entry-team_average`.`team` AS `team`, 

SUM(`view-entry-team_average`.`team_average`) AS `Team Total by Date`, <-- this is the important part

`time_dimension`.`db_date` AS `db_date`,..... all ids are here 
FROM (`time_dimension`
LEFT JOIN `view-entry-team_average` ON(((`time_dimension`.`db_date` >= `view-entry-team_average`.`start_date`) AND (`time_dimension`.`db_date` < `view-entry-team_average`.`end_date`))))
```

***I do not know if there is a better way to connect the view (start and end dates) to the time dimension one***

After that, I am using **MySQL WITH ROLLUP** to summarize the data, grouping by business_unit_id and department_id and team_id in order to provide the "overview" by each of these dimensions.

Great! It works perfectly for small amount of data, including the ROLLUP.

## Problem

However, when assessing hundreds of team, in 6 months period,  it stop responding any query I made, and phpMyAdmin stop responding, even if I open a new window. As it is a cloud server, I am not confident how to extract more info from that server. Then, if I reduce the assessed period for just one month, then it works fine.

Has anyone already used **MySql** to create a relationship between the fact (based in a period) and time dimension? Does anyone has used this solution with a **ROLLUP** feature? Does anyone know any material / link / sample that can tell me about that?

Comment: Your question is, basically, one of query performance. I think we'll need more information from you to help you. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then,if it makes sense, [edit] your question.  Also, can you tell us more about what you mean by "it crashes the server database?" Does your `mysqld` process stop?

Comment: @O.Jones, thank you for your prompt answer. After reading that link you sent, I realize that my question is not good and I am going to elaborate my question.
When I said "it crashes the server database" , please read " it stop responding any query I made, phpMyAdmin stop responding, even if I open a new window. As it is a cloud server, I am not confident how to extract more info from that server".

Comment: @Gustavo - Perhaps you have hit some limit?  Did it free up after an hour or so?